# HomePod with Apple Music family

Tags: apple-music, family-sharing, homepod

**How to use a HomePod with several Apple accounts?**

I currently have a family plan for two people: myself and my friend. I also have a HomePod, on which I listen to my music.

My friend has an Android phone with the Apple Music App (but has a MacBook). Can we listen to her playlists on the HomePod?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what's the actual question? 1. Is it possible to listen to her playlists in anyway on the HomePod? 2. Is it possible to play their music through the HomePod Siri? 3. Is it possible to play their songs from their Android device straight into the HomePod? 4. Something else?

Comment: My question is mainly 1. but also 2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using AirPlay from their phone?

According to [this guide](https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/11/03/how-to-set-up-multiple-users-on-a-homepod), they must first be a part of your home network. [This Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/guide/homepod/change-settings-apde6dc8093d/homepod) describes 4 simple steps for sharing your home accessories with others. In essence:

1. On the Home tab, tap the More button, tap Home Settings, then tap Invite People.
2. Tap the Add button to choose people with an Apple ID from your contacts list, or enter their Apple ID email addresses in the To field.
3. Tap Send Invite.
4. Ask your friend to do one of the following:

   a. On iOS/iPadOS: In the notification, tap Accept.

   b. On iOS/iPadOS: In the Home app, tap the More button, tap Home Settings, then tap their name.

   c. On Apple TV: Tap Show Me on Apple TV, then turn on one or more Apple TVs.

   d. [On Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208709): In the Home app, tap the More button, tap Home Settings, Select View under Invitations, Select Accept, then Done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This issue is that they don’t have an iOS device. I found an old iPhone but it is on iOS 12

Comment: I want then to use the HomePod via Siri to access their music.

Comment: [Try this Apple support page.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208709) The first two sections explain how to send and accept invites on both iOS and macOS.

Comment: We have already done that: she has control of various things on the Mac Home app. But she still cannot play her playlist by saying « Hey Siri, play [some name] playlist »

Comment: I'm not aware if it's currently possible. Siri on your HomePod is tied to your account. Guests can only share via AirPlay. You could try "Hey Siri, play [friend]'s [playlist] playlist" replacing [friend] and [playlist] respectively, although I have not tried this myself.

Comment: But she is part of my family… thanks for your interest

Answer (score -1):

Use [BabelPod](https://github.com/maexdaemaege/babelpod). This is how I stream from my Android to a BabelPod server to a HomePod.

BabelPod's fork was even updated pretty [recently](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomePod/comments/n52got/babelpod_lives_output_audio_to_homepod_from/) so it should be fine.

Comment: How does this work - what is BabelPod?

Comment: [BabelPod](https://github.com/maexdaemaege/babelpod) transfers the audio from your Android device to your BabelPod server and from there to the aforementioned HomePod. As I mentioned before BabelPod is a living project so the installation and running instructions are most up-to-date in the repository I linked.